# C++/CLI Mixed mode library in CLR Profiler - Surviving GC Handles of Type LanguageSupport.Initialize

Tags: memory-leaks, c++-cli

I profiled the mixed mode C++/CLI wrapper I am writing in CLR profiler and found many surviving GC Handles of the type LanguageSupport.Initialize, I read a few threads on this [Module Initializer](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214141518/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx), but couldn't say whether its a cause of concern. Should I be worried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of these handles doesn't increase over time, then I don't think you need to worry about it.